# How to select classes with partial string match in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="xyz">
<cite class="abc hello pqr">Text inside</cite>
<cite class="hello">Text inside</cite>
<cite class="abc hello">Text inside</cite>
</div>
```

This is an example of a class with the substring "hello". Using JavaScript, I want to select all the classes in which "hello" occurs and also further modify the `innerHTML` of the selected classes. Do note that the substring can occur anywhere in the class name.

All the question I've come across only have the option to select all the elements with the `id` containing the substring.
Eg.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="hello-"]');
```

When I modified to make it work for classes

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="hello-"]');
```

It doesn't work at all.

I need the code which works in finding all the classes in which "hello" is a substring of and to further modify the `innerHTML` of the selected classes. Please suggest the code only using JavaScript

Comment: Your code is selecting elements whose `class` attribute *begins* with `hello-`. None of them do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the attribute selector `*`, you're using `^`

So, following your example

```js
// from
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="hello-"]');

// to
document.querySelectorAll('[class*="hello"]');
```

You have a slight miss-conception on how attribute selectors work

What you're doing by using `[class^="hello-"]` is matching all classes that BEGIN with `hello-`

Using the other example, `[class*="hello"]`, you're matching all classes that contain `hello`

You can check the [W3C Selectors Overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview) for more information. It's similar to how you'd use a RegEx.

Answer (score -3):

Use a `.` when calling `querySelectorAll` to indicate a class name to find.

```js
for (const cite of document.querySelectorAll('.hello')) {
  cite.textContent = 'new text';
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <cite class="abc hello pqr">Text inside</cite>
  <cite class="hello">Text inside</cite>
  <cite class="abc hello">Text inside</cite>
  <cite class="abc">don't match me</cite>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're looking for a specific class, you don't select it as a substring. You use the special `.class` selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".hello")
```